# What's the meaning of 'Total acceleration effective'?

Tags: vibration

I'm reading a document describing the procedure to do a random vibration test. In it, a PSD (Power Density Curve) curve is defined, and there's a note at the bottom of the curve:

```
Total acceleration effective: 50 to 500 Hz = 2.0G
```

What does it mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a discrete system with $N$ degrees of freedom, the displacement  can be expressed as
$$
  \mathbf{u}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \boldsymbol{\Phi}_i \Gamma_i s_i(\omega_i, t)
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Phi}_i$ is the mode shape, $\Gamma_i$ is the participation factor, and $s_i$ is a function of the modal frequency, $\omega_i$.

The second derivative of the displacement, $\ddot{\mathbf{u}}$ (with respect to time, $t$) gives the **total** acceleration.  Some corrections are needed when all the $N$ modes are not known.

In your case, the modes chosen are only between 50 Hz and 500 Hz.  Therefore, the term **effective** has been used.

To get the **g** value, the acceleration ($\ddot{\mathbf{u}}$) is divided by the acceleration due to gravity.